# In the Bing Maps API, what's the difference between the Master Key and the Query Key? Is either key sensitive?

Tags: bing-maps

In activating my Bing Maps account, I am issued a "Master Key" and a "Query Key". API methods accept only a single key, and only the "Master Key" seems to work for those API calls. What, if any, is the difference between these two keys? Should I consider either of these keys "sensitive" and avoid exposing them to end users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any Bing Maps key can be used as a Master or Query key when creating a data source. However, a query key can only query data and has the equivalent of read-only rights, where as a master key has full access to edit/delete and query a data source. In production apps you should have use two keys, one as the master key that you keep internally, and the other as the query key which you include in your app which,, if someone where to get ahold of, would only allow them to read your data and not vandalize it.

Comment: I was unable to find any documentation one way or the other. I can only assume that this is the right answer @rbrundritt. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on the Bing Maps team. It is the right answer. There is some documentation on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585130.aspx